# Chopping a large number into its digits then adding them in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program where whatever a number is entered by the user, the digits composing that number are added, and if they sum to 10, it is good, if not then they've done something wrong. This should be simple I suppose. Though I'm struggling to add together the numbers after I split them. Do you know what I have to do?

This is my attempt:

```
    num=raw_input("input number?")
num.split() = a
if sum(a) == 10:
  print num + "is a valid number."
else:
  print num + "is invalid!"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

or you can use the `map` function:

```
In [1]: a="1234567890"

In [2]: map(int,a)
Out[2]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

In [3]: sum(map(int,a))
Out[3]: 45
```

map(function, sequence) calls function(item) for each of the sequence’s items and returns a list of the return values. See [docs.python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) This works because `raw_input` returns a string.

Comment: Thanks Fredrik!!! Just out of curiosity - is there another way I could do by using iteration? I'd like to get more exposed to it! Many thanks from Australia!

Answer (score 4):

`split.num()` doesn't do anything. `num.split()` would be valid, but doesn't solve the problem, as it splits on spaces. What you want is to convert the digit characters in `num` to the numbers they represent, which you can do with a list comprehension:

```
digits = [int(c) for c in num]
```

Then `sum` the result of that expression.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `raw_input()` to prompt the user, this function returns a string (composed of digits in your case), if you need to make computations on them, you have to convert them with `int()` before. Here is how your code could look like:

```
num = raw_input('input number: ')
if sum(int(i) for i in num) == 10:
    print "OK"
else:
    print "FAILED"
```

Keep in mind that in `Python 2.x`, there are 2 functions, `raw_input()` returns a string, and `input()` returns integers (or fails if something else is given), while in `Python 3.x` the `raw_input()` function has been replaced by `input()`.

Comment: this is problem a stupid question but where you have introduced 'i', how does python know that you are referring to each of the digits from the input?

Comment: other than that thank you very much for your answer it is perfect and has helped me a lot.

Comment: @rooney: You can imagine that Python reads ahead far enough to see that in `(int(i) for i in num)`, `i` is each value in turn. Basically it executes the expression `int(i)` multiple times, in a context that includes the right value of `i`. Remember that you don't have to declare variables in advance in Python, it looks them up as needed, so the syntax for list comprehensions and generator expressions follows that through.